# Как сверстать флетовый плейлист в перспективе?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно сверстать плейлист, который будет состоять из квадратиков , которые будут разспологаться в перспективе. Чтоб оставалась возможность дописать функционал , на js. уезжание квадратиков в перед и появление новых заде. Может такое уже гдето реализовано или знаете где про это почитать дайте ссылку.

Вот скрин чтоб было понятно о чем речь:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, экспериментируй.

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 25%;
  border: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(40deg);
  top: -250px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); } body { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #B5B5B5; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg); }
```